# Changing the keymapping to the Left Windows Key to open a program

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, start-menu

I've been looking around online and can't seem to find a solid answer on this. I would like to change the way my left windows acts. I really dislike the way Windows 8 has the menu structure. I like the old start menu. There is a start menu program that I would like to map to the Windows key (if possible). Any help or direction on where to get this working would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: What program? If it's a program designed to work as a start menu, such as Start8, they will override the windows key automatically.

Comment: It's Lenovo Start Menu

Comment: After a quick search, it looks like Lenovo Start Menu is called Pokki. http://www.pokki.com/ Have you tried installing that? I would imagine it would rebind your Windows key automatically.

Comment: @Adam I will give that a shot in a little bit. Thanks!